# Running a Python script from Access VBA

Tags: python, vba, ms-access

I'm having trouble finding many resources, but I'm trying to get vba to run a python script

```
Const pyScript = "C:\Test\Weekend_Exceptions\Weekend_Exception.py"
Dim dblRetVal As Double
dblRetVal = Shell("C:\Python34\python.exe " & pyScript)
```

I know my python script works and should output a file, but its not. Additionally the vba is not tirggering a debug flag so I'm not sure where I am wrong. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't give too much details so i'll make some assumptions

Probably your python script read some local file this will cause your script to raise a FileNotFoundError and exit

To make the test copy the entire arg string to Shell, in your case "C:\Python34\python.exe C:\Test\Weekend_Exceptions\Weekend_Exception.py", open a cmd with Win+r , paste and run, not being in the right directory should raise the same error.

If this is the problem, make a makestuff.bat file with the code

```
@echo off
@cd C:\Test\Weekend_Exceptions\
@C:\Python34\python.exe Weekend_Exception.py
@echo on
```

Then call the bat from Shell("C:\Place\of\your\bat\makestuff.bat")

Return with more details to we work on a solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did:

1. I created a File1.bat to open the File2.py. The code in File1.bat is:

> ```
> @echo off
> @h:
> @cd H:\Path\Cronus\Rangers
> @C:\Python3\python.exe File2.py
> @echo on
> ```

Note that File2.py is inside H:\Path\Cronus\Rangers folder. That's why we need to open it before.

2. I created a function in VBA to open a .bat file:

> ```
> Option Compare Database
>
> Function MacroPythonSARH()
> On Error GoTo MacroPythonSARH_Err
>
> Call Shell("H:\Path\Cronus\Rangers\File1.bat", 1)
>
> MacroPythonSARH_Exit:
>     Exit Function
>
> MacroPythonSARH_Err:
>     MsgBox Error$
>     Resume MacroPythonSARH_Exit
>
> End Function
> ```